# How to copy a row and paste it X amount of times

Tags: vba

I simply need to copy a number of rows based on the number in a cell.

In Sheet1 I have a table and in Sheet4 I have a list of values.

I require row at A6 to be copied by and then pasted the number of times as specified in F2 in Sheet 4.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Please note that Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, it is for answering specific, well defined questions about why your already existing code is not working. Here is a link on how to ask a question:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use the recorder and read the generated code.

Comment: You asked 9 questions and only marked 1 as answered. Have some respect for those who help you and properly close your questions if they got a valid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start from this (adjust where needed):

```
range("d4:g4").Resize(worksheets("sheet4").range("f2").value,4).FillDown
```